# Need to put the local scope in to a angular uigrid/nggrid cellTemplate

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have a local scope

```
$scope.edit="Edit btn";
```

I need to put the local scope in to a angular uigrid `cellTemplate`. 
How could be it possible?

```
cellTemplate: '<button id="editBtn" type="button" class="btn-small edit-btn" ng-click="grid.appScope.editeUser(row.entity)" >{{edit}}</button>
```

Comment: use the searchbox at the top of this page and type something like `[angularjs] cellTemplate ui-grid` you will find similar questions/answers. Give it a shot ! and if you figure out an answer, then post it as a possible solution [meta: etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) GL!

Comment: also, it usually helps to provide all relevant, related and minimal parts of your code (not necessarily the entire app), in a plunker or jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks Guys !  it get resolved by using  grid.appScope